# Divide option tag horizontally in two parts (columns)?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to divide an option list into two parts (columns)? For an example that an option has a text that is on the left side and an other that is on the right, but in the same row.

Example:

```
+--------------------select options-----------------------+
    option1                      option text for text1
    option2                      option text for text1
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: in which language or script you want to achieve this?

Comment: html and css and also the other web languages

Comment: you can try optiongroup, sample on link - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_optgroup

Answer (score 0):

While I'd suggest using a styled `<ul>`, or `<ol>`, to do this using JavaScript and CSS, it's possible – though not necessarily reliable or pretty – to do this with JavaScript; there is, however, *no* way to do this with native HTML or CSS, particularly since an `<option>` element can't contain child-nodes which means that CSS can't target, or separate, individual columns with `padding` or `text-align` or any other means.

However, with JavaScript, one approach is as follows; here I've extended the prototype of the `HTMLSelectElement`, which means that this is used as a method of that element-type, this can – be considered problematic if this method isn't documented adequately in comments in order that colleages, should you have any, don't accidentally encounter, or over-write, it. That said, however, I do consider it a convenience, however I'll offer a more 'functional' (perhaps 'less-invasive') approach later in this answer. That said, here's the first iteration of my answer (explanation of the code is in the code's comments):

```js
HTMLSelectElement.prototype.optionColumnize = function(opts) {
  // caching a reference to the 'this' Node, which will be
  // (barring binding/applying etc) a <select> element:
  var select = this,

    // caching the options of the <select> element, using
    // Function.prototype.call() and Array.prototype.slice()
    // to create an Array of those options (rather than a
    // NodeList/collection:
    options = Array.prototype.slice.call(select.options, 0),

    // iterating over the Array of <option> elements in
    // in order to find the <option> with the most
    // text, using Array.prototype.reduce() to compare
    // the length of the current <option> against the
    // previous <option>, and retaining the <option>
    // with the greatest length:
    greatestOption = options.reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a.text.length > b.text.length ? a : b;
    }),

    // initialising the default settings of the method:
    s = {
      // String: defining the character which should
      // separate the columns:
      'separator': '/',

      // Number or String: defining the character-length
      // of the between 'column' spacing (whatever
      // argument is given will be passed to parseInt()
      // prior to use):
      'paddingLength': 5,

      // String: characters from which the padding string
      // will be created; this string will be repeated
      // by the 'paddingLength' (above) variable:
      'paddingString': '&nbsp;'
    };

  // iterating over the user-supplied opts Object to employ
  // user-defined settings:
  for (var prop in opts) {

    // if the opts Object has property set by the user
    // (ie not a property inherited from its prototype
    // chain):
    if (opts.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {

      // we set the property of the default
      // settings Object ('s') to be equal to
      // that set in the opts Object:
      s[prop] = opts[prop];
    }
  }

  // splitting the columns of the greatestOption (found above)
  // into an Array by splitting the string of text by the
  // character supplied by the s.separator setting:
  var greatestOptionColumns = greatestOption.text.split(s.separator),

    // finding the integer represented by the s.paddingLength
    // property, converting the value into a base-10 number:
    paddingLength = parseInt(s.paddingLength, 10),

    // creating two variables (currently undefined) to be
    // used within the loop (below):
    columns,
    textDelta;

  // iterating over each of the <option> elements held in the
  // options Array, using Array.prototype.forEach() to do so:
  options.forEach(function(opt) {
    // the first argument of the anonymous function,
    // (here 'opt') is the current array-element of
    // the array over which we're iterating.

    // splitting the text of the current <option> of
    // the options Array by the supplied string held
    // in the s.separator property, this returns an
    // array over which we iterate with the
    // Array.prototype.map() function to return a new
    // Array to the 'columns' variable:
    columns = opt.text.split(s.separator).map(function(col, index, allCols) {
      // 'col': the current element of the created array,
      // index: the index of the current array-element,
      // allCols: the full array.

      // if the current array-element is less than the
      // length of the Array - 1 (Length is one-based,
      // JavaScript Arrays have zero-based indexing):
      if (index < allCols.length - 1) {

        // we find the difference between the text-length
        // of the current element and the element of the
        // same index in the greatestOptionColumns Array:
        textDelta = greatestOptionColumns[index].length - col.length;

        // here we return the current array-element + the padding string,
        // created via String.prototype.repeat(), which is chained to
        // a String ('s.paddingString') and a numeric argument
        // ('paddingLength + textDelta') to create a new String
        // of 's.paddingString' by the number of times supplied as
        // the numeric argument ('n'.repeat(3) -> 'nnn'):
        return col + s.paddingString.repeat(paddingLength + textDelta);

        // otherwise (if we are the last array-element of the
        // current array
      } else {

        // we simply return the existing array-element
        // so we don't have any 'trailing' padding:
        return col;
      }
    });

    // setting the innerHTML of the current <option> element
    // to the contents of the columns Array, using
    // Array.prototype.join() to join the elements together
    // with an empty-string:
    opt.innerHTML = columns.join('');
  });
};

// calling the function with no arguments:
document.getElementById('demo1').optionColumnize();

// calling the function, and changing the padding-length to 10:
document.getElementById('demo2').optionColumnize({
  'paddingLength': 10
});

// calling the function, and changing the padding-String to '~':
document.getElementById('demo3').optionColumnize({
  'paddingString': '~'
});

// calling the function, and changing the column-separator to 'o':
document.getElementById('demo4').optionColumnize({
  'separator': 'o'
});

// calling the function, and changing:
// - column-separator to 'n',
// - padding-length to 7,
// - padding-string to '+'
document.getElementById('demo5').optionColumnize({
  'separator': 'n',
  'paddingLength': '7',
  'paddingString': '+'
});
```

```css
select {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<select id="demo1">
  <option value="1">option 1/value 1/column3</option>
  <option value="2">option 2/value 2/column3</option>
  <option value="3">option 3/value 3/column3</option>
  <option value="4">option 4/value 4/column3</option>
  <option value="5">option 5/value 5/column3</option>
  <option value="6">option 6/value 6/column3</option>
  <option value="7">option 7/value 7/column3</option>
  <option value="8">option 8/value 8/column3</option>
  <option value="9">option 9/value 9/column3</option>
  <option value="10">option 10/value 9/column3</option>
</select>
<select id="demo2">
  <option value="1">option 1/value 1/column3</option>
  <option value="2">option 2/value 2/column3</option>
  <option value="3">option 3/value 3/column3</option>
  <option value="4">option 4/value 4/column3</option>
  <option value="5">option 5/value 5/column3</option>
  <option value="6">option 6/value 6/column3</option>
  <option value="7">option 7/value 7/column3</option>
  <option value="8">option 8/value 8/column3</option>
  <option value="9">option 9/value 9/column3</option>
  <option value="10">option 10/value 9/column3</option>
</select>
<select id="demo3">
  <option value="1">option 1/value 1/column3</option>
  <option value="2">option 2/value 2/column3</option>
  <option value="3">option 3/value 3/column3</option>
  <option value="4">option 4/value 4/column3</option>
  <option value="5">option 5/value 5/column3</option>
  <option value="6">option 6/value 6/column3</option>
  <option value="7">option 7/value 7/column3</option>
  <option value="8">option 8/value 8/column3</option>
  <option value="9">option 9/value 9/column3</option>
  <option value="10">option 10/value 9/column3</option>
</select>
<select id="demo4">
  <option value="1">option 1/value 1/column3</option>
  <option value="2">option 2/value 2/column3</option>
  <option value="3">option 3/value 3/column3</option>
  <option value="4">option 4/value 4/column3</option>
  <option value="5">option 5/value 5/column3</option>
  <option value="6">option 6/value 6/column3</option>
  <option value="7">option 7/value 7/column3</option>
  <option value="8">option 8/value 8/column3</option>
  <option value="9">option 9/value 9/column3</option>
  <option value="10">option 10/value 9/column3</option>
</select>
<select id="demo5">
  <option value="1">option 1/value 1/column3</option>
  <option value="2">option 2/value 2/column3</option>
  <option value="3">option 3/value 3/column3</option>
  <option value="4">option 4/value 4/column3</option>
  <option value="5">option 5/value 5/column3</option>
  <option value="6">option 6/value 6/column3</option>
  <option value="7">option 7/value 7/column3</option>
  <option value="8">option 8/value 8/column3</option>
  <option value="9">option 9/value 9/column3</option>
  <option value="10">option 10/value 9/column3</option>
</select>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/prvfs11b/) for experimentation or development.

An alternate take on the above, of course, is to use it as a 'regular' function, rather than as a method of the `HTMLSelectElement`; to use it like so we have to pass the relevant Node to the function, and – ideally, but not compulsorily &ndash check that the supplied Node is a `<select>` element. To do this, a slight alteration of the above is as follows:

```js
function optionColumnize(el, opts) {
  // caching a reference to the Node upon which we're working,
  // and ensuring it's a select element (otherwise we return
  // from the function):
  if (el.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'select') {
    var select = el;
  } else {
    return false;
  }

  // caching the options of the <select> element, using
  // Function.prototype.call() and Array.prototype.slice()
  // to create an Array of those options (rather than a
  // NodeList/collection:
  options = Array.prototype.slice.call(select.options, 0),

    // iterating over the Array of <option> elements in
    // in order to find the <option> with the most
    // text, using Array.prototype.reduce() to compare
    // the length of the current <option> against the
    // previous <option>, and retaining the <option>
    // with the greatest length:
    greatestOption = options.reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a.text.length > b.text.length ? a : b;
    }),

    // initialising the default settings of the method:
    s = {
      // String: defining the character which should
      // separate the columns:
      'separator': '/',

      // Number or String: defining the character-length
      // of the between 'column' spacing (whatever
      // argument is given will be passed to parseInt()
      // prior to use):
      'paddingLength': 5,

      // String: characters from which the padding string
      // will be created; this string will be repeated
      // by the 'paddingLength' (above) variable:
      'paddingString': '&nbsp;'
    };

  // iterating over the user-supplied opts Object to employ
  // user-defined settings:
  for (var prop in opts) {

    // if the opts Object has property set by the user
    // (ie not a property inherited from its prototype
    // chain):
    if (opts.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {

      // we set the property of the default
      // settings Object ('s') to be equal to
      // that set in the opts Object:
      s[prop] = opts[prop];
    }
  }

  // splitting the columns of the greatestOption (found above)
  // into an Array by splitting the string of text by the
  // character supplied by the s.separator setting:
  var greatestOptionColumns = greatestOption.text.split(s.separator),

    // finding the integer represented by the s.paddingLength
    // property, converting the value into a base-10 number:
    paddingLength = parseInt(s.paddingLength, 10),

    // creating two variables (currently undefined) to be
    // used within the loop (below):
    columns,
    textDelta;

  // iterating over each of the <option> elements held in the
  // options Array, using Array.prototype.forEach() to do so:
  options.forEach(function(opt) {
    // the first argument of the anonymous function,
    // (here 'opt') is the current array-element of
    // the array over which we're iterating.

    // splitting the text of the current <option> of
    // the options Array by the supplied string held
    // in the s.separator property, this returns an
    // array over which we iterate with the
    // Array.prototype.map() function to return a new
    // Array to the 'columns' variable:
    columns = opt.text.split(s.separator).map(function(col, index, allCols) {
      // 'col': the current element of the created array,
      // index: the index of the current array-element,
      // allCols: the full array.

      // if the current array-element is less than the
      // length of the Array - 1 (Length is one-based,
      // JavaScript Arrays have zero-based indexing):
      if (index < allCols.length - 1) {

        // we find the difference between the text-length
        // of the current element and the element of the
        // same index in the greatestOptionColumns Array:
        textDelta = greatestOptionColumns[index].length - col.length;

        // here we return the current array-element + the padding string,
        // created via String.prototype.repeat(), which is chained to
        // a String ('s.paddingString') and a numeric argument
        // ('paddingLength + textDelta') to create a new String
        // of 's.paddingString' by the number of times supplied as
        // the numeric argument ('n'.repeat(3) -> 'nnn'):
        return col + s.paddingString.repeat(paddingLength + textDelta);

        // otherwise (if we are the last array-element of the
        // current array
      } else {

        // we simply return the existing array-element
        // so we don't have any 'trailing' padding:
        return col;
      }
    });

    // setting the innerHTML of the current <option> element
    // to the contents of the columns Array, using
    // Array.prototype.join() to join the elements together
    // with an empty-string:
    opt.innerHTML = columns.join('');
  });
};

// calling the function with no arguments:
optionColumnize(document.getElementById('demo1'));

// calling the function, and changing the padding-length to 10:
optionColumnize(document.getElementById('demo2'), {
  'paddingLength': 10
});

// calling the function, and changing the padding-String to '~':
optionColumnize(document.getElementById('demo3'), {
  'paddingString': '~'
});

// calling the function, and changing the separator to 'o':
optionColumnize(document.getElementById('demo4'), {
  'separator': 'o'
});

// calling the function, and changing:
// - column-separator to 'n',
// - padding-length to 7,
// - padding-string to '+'
optionColumnize(document.getElementById('demo5'), {
  'separator': 'n',
  'paddingLength': '7',
  'paddingString': '+'
});
```

```css
select {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<select id="demo1">
  <option value="1">option 1/value 1/column3</option>
  <option value="2">option 2/value 2/column3</option>
  <option value="3">option 3/value 3/column3</option>
  <option value="4">option 4/value 4/column3</option>
  <option value="5">option 5/value 5/column3</option>
  <option value="6">option 6/value 6/column3</option>
  <option value="7">option 7/value 7/column3</option>
  <option value="8">option 8/value 8/column3</option>
  <option value="9">option 9/value 9/column3</option>
  <option value="10">option 10/value 9/column3</option>
</select>
<select id="demo2">
  <option value="1">option 1/value 1/column3</option>
  <option value="2">option 2/value 2/column3</option>
  <option value="3">option 3/value 3/column3</option>
  <option value="4">option 4/value 4/column3</option>
  <option value="5">option 5/value 5/column3</option>
  <option value="6">option 6/value 6/column3</option>
  <option value="7">option 7/value 7/column3</option>
  <option value="8">option 8/value 8/column3</option>
  <option value="9">option 9/value 9/column3</option>
  <option value="10">option 10/value 9/column3</option>
</select>
<select id="demo3">
  <option value="1">option 1/value 1/column3</option>
  <option value="2">option 2/value 2/column3</option>
  <option value="3">option 3/value 3/column3</option>
  <option value="4">option 4/value 4/column3</option>
  <option value="5">option 5/value 5/column3</option>
  <option value="6">option 6/value 6/column3</option>
  <option value="7">option 7/value 7/column3</option>
  <option value="8">option 8/value 8/column3</option>
  <option value="9">option 9/value 9/column3</option>
  <option value="10">option 10/value 9/column3</option>
</select>
<select id="demo4">
  <option value="1">option 1/value 1/column3</option>
  <option value="2">option 2/value 2/column3</option>
  <option value="3">option 3/value 3/column3</option>
  <option value="4">option 4/value 4/column3</option>
  <option value="5">option 5/value 5/column3</option>
  <option value="6">option 6/value 6/column3</option>
  <option value="7">option 7/value 7/column3</option>
  <option value="8">option 8/value 8/column3</option>
  <option value="9">option 9/value 9/column3</option>
  <option value="10">option 10/value 9/column3</option>
</select>
<select id="demo5">
  <option value="1">option 1/value 1/column3</option>
  <option value="2">option 2/value 2/column3</option>
  <option value="3">option 3/value 3/column3</option>
  <option value="4">option 4/value 4/column3</option>
  <option value="5">option 5/value 5/column3</option>
  <option value="6">option 6/value 6/column3</option>
  <option value="7">option 7/value 7/column3</option>
  <option value="8">option 8/value 8/column3</option>
  <option value="9">option 9/value 9/column3</option>
  <option value="10">option 10/value 9/column3</option>
</select>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/prvfs11b/1/) for experimentation or development.

References:

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
- [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).
- [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
- [`Element.tagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName).
- [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
- [`HTMLOptionElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement).
- [`HTMLSelectElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement).
- [`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).
- [`String.prototype.repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat).
- [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/split).
- [`String.prototype.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase).

Answer (score -1):

I found a way around this. It will not be perfectly like you want but i think it should work for you.

its a bit tricky and also long. I post a jsfiddle file for you:

```
*http://jsfiddle.net/7c5qr0h9/8/*
```

(i used the * to fit for the qualifications of an answer)

Maybe that would be a way to a result. Check it out!